# How to serialize a PHP object into a JavaScript object (Not JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

I've used `json_encode($array);` to convert an array to a json.

```
[{"x":1418736600,"y":"82.2"},{"x":1418736900,"y":"82.2"}]
```

But what I really need is a JavaScript object like the following:

```
[{x:1418736600,y:"82.2"},{x:1418736900,y:"82.2"}]
```

To make it short I would like a JSON without quoting the keys, but it would be preferable avoiding parsing what `json_encode` outputs and using a more straightforward way instead.

Is it possible to do this in PHP?

Comment: Why do you need this? The output of `json_encode` is perfectly valid *JavaScript* code, if you use it where a value is expected. It's perfectly valid in JavaScript to put the keys in quotes. It seems unlikely that the quoted keys are making the payload so much bigger that that's an issue.

Comment: Just a note: JSON is also valid Javascript, since Javascript object literals keys' can be either quoted or unquoted (though they must be quoted if they are not valid identifiers).

Comment: Write your own *Javascript object literal* encoder, which would be a modified offshoot of a JSON encoder. Practically speaking through, this is absolutely nonsense, as *JSON already is Javascript*.

Comment: Unquoted keys are not valid JSON, so I doubt you can do that with `json_encode`. But as all the others already mentioned it should not be necessary anyway.

Comment: ..and just to add onto all the previous comments, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. Anything JSON will be parseable by raw vanilla JS as a raw object. If your *values* shouldn't be quoted, you can cast them inside of PHP (to bool, float, int, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than making the payload *very slightly smaller*, there's no need to do this. The output of `json_encode` is valid JavaScript code, if used where a value is expected, e.g.:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

The quoted property keys are valid JavaScript. JSON as a whole is, in fact, a subset of JavaScript literal syntax.

You *could* throw a regular expression at the result. It can probably never be perfect (JSON, like HTML, can't be correctly parsed with a single regular expression), but within a limited domain you might be able to do it. For instance, here's a naive version that would probably work for many data sets, including your example, though again it would **not** work with all data sets by any means:

```
<?php
$str = json_encode($array);
$str = preg_replace('/"([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)":/', '$1:', $str);
?>
var x = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

That assumes anything that consists of just A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, or $ between double quotes followed immediately by a colon is a key and removes the quotes. (That's not a complete list of valid [JavaScript identifier characters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords), it's just an example.)

But it seems unlikely to me that the savings are worth the bother.

To do it correctly, of course, you'd have to do your own serializer. It wouldn't be all that hard, just a recursive function that handles descending into arrays and objects. It could still use `json_encode` for the values.